# error C2039: 'bind2nd': is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, std, bind2nd

I am working on converting a VS2008 C++ program to VS2017 and am running into the error:

```
error C2039: 'bind2nd': is not a member of 'std'
```

Did some searching and found one recommendation to make the int a size_t, that had no effect.  Any more thoughts?